# How to store the grep output into a variable inside a loop?

Tags: shell, loops, grep

I would like to count the number of outputs produced by this loop

```
cd /System/Library/Extensions
find *.kext -prune -type d | while read d; do
     codesign -v "$d" 2>&1 | grep "invalid signature"
done
```

How can I store or count the outputs? If tried with arrays, counters etc. but it seems I can't get anything outside of that loop.

Comment: you need the count for each `codesign -v "$d" 2>&1` or overall count of the while loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To obtain the number of lines produced by the while loop, the `wc` word count can be used

```
cd /System/Library/Extensions
find *.kext -prune -type d | while read d; do
     codesign -v "$d" 2>&1 | grep "invalid signature"
done | wc -l
```

- `wc -l` the -l option counts the number of lines in the input, which is piped to the output of `while`

Now if you need to count the number of `grep` outputs in each iteration of the while loop, the `-c` option of `grep` would be usefull.

```
cd /System/Library/Extensions
find *.kext -prune -type d | while read d; do
    codesign -v "$d" 2>&1 | grep -c "invalid signature"
done
```

- `-c` Suppress normal output; instead print a count of matching  lines
            for  each  input  file

Comment: Thanks a lot! the wc -l command did the trick. Two things I ended up changing: 1) I added "| tr -d ' '" after "wc -l", to remove a couple unwanted spaces that were appearing in the output. 2) I stored the result in a variable by wrapping the code as such: output=$(code)

Comment: @DavidD You are always welcome :) glad to know i was of some help

Answer (score 1):

classical difficulty in subshell is to pass variables back.

here one way to get this information back :

```
cd /System/Library/Extensions

RESULT=$(find *.kext -prune -type d | {
# we are in a sub-subshell ... 
GCOUNT=0
DIRCOUNT=0
FAILDIR=0
while read d; do
     COUNT=$(codesign -v "$d" 2>&1 | grep -c "invalid signature")
     if [[ -n $COUNT ]]
     then
     if [[ $COUNT > 0 ]]
     then
         echo "[ERROR] $COUNT invalid signature found in $d" >&2
         GCOUNT=$(( $GCOUNT + $COUNT ))
         FAILDIR=$(( $FAILDIR + 1 ))
     fi
     else
     echo "[ERROR] wrong invalid signature count for $d" >&2
     fi
     DIRCOUNT=$(( $DIRCOUNT + 1 ))
done
# this is the actual result, that's why all other output of this subshell are redirected
echo "$DIRCOUNT $FAILDIR $GCOUNT"
})

# parse result integers separated by a space.
if [[ $RESULT =~ ([0-9]+)\ ([0-9]+)\ ([0-9]+) ]]
then
    DIRCOUNT=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    FAILDIR=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    COUNT=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
else
    echo "[ERROR] Invalid result format. Please check your script $0" >&2
fi

if [[ -n $COUNT ]]
then
    echo "$COUNT errors found in $FAILDIR/$DIRCOUNT directories"
fi
```